# How to set a variable's initial type to T?

Tags: c#, types, enums

I'm currently making a networking library. I created a class called Packet that has a PacketType enum that determines what is this packet for.

```
public enum PacketType
{
   ConnectionOpen,
   KeepAlive,
   ConnectionClose
}

public class Packet
{
    PacketType packetType;
}
```

If the user wants to add more packet types, how does he do that?
I *don't* want to set the Packet's PacketType every time when it gets created like this:

```
public class Packet<T>
{
    T packetType;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood generics. You should read a little bit about this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/

T in you case is a class and not a value. You describe default values for implementations. You could do this with an abstract class:

```cs
#region Your Library
public enum PacketType
{
    ConnectionOpen,
    KeepAlive,
    ConnectionClose
}

public abstract class Packet
{
    public abstract PacketType PacketType { get; }
}
#endregion

#region Your Implementation
public class MyPacketForKeppAlive : Packet
{
    public override PacketType PacketType => PacketType.KeepAlive;
}
public class MyPacketConnectionOpen : Packet
{
    public override PacketType PacketType => PacketType.ConnectionOpen;
}

internal static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Packet[] packets = new Packet[]
        {
            new MyPacketForKeppAlive(),
            new MyPacketConnectionOpen()
        };

    foreach (Packet p in packets)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.PacketType);
    }
}
#endregion
```